# Meta-analysis of survival probabilities from single-arm studies

Tags: survival, meta-analysis

I am performing a meta-analysis of survival outcomes (expressed as % progression-free survival or overall survival at 1/2 years) from single-arm studies. I am using R package 'meta' with function 'metaprop', following the methodology of some other meta-analyses in the field. I was pointed out that the measures of effect are actually not proportions, but probabilities, and should be analyzed differently. I understand that assuming proportions does not take into account censoring; however, I did not find any direct way to perform a meta-analysis of probabilities - in the package 'meta' the only implemented summary measures of binary outcome data seem to be applicable to more than one group designs (OR, RR, risk difference etc.).

Can someone help me in identifying the correct method and implementation of doing this analysis?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? Assuming that multiple studies have the same underlying distribution for survival (incl. at some fixed timepoint) or that this may vary a bit across studies?

As you point out, one distinction is between binary proportions (every patient is 1/0) and time-to-event (everyone has an event time, but we may not always observe it) and survival probabilities (looking at the probability of an event by a fixed time based on an underlying time-to-event analysis). In principle, there's several options to address all of these:

1. 2-step meta-analysis of logit-proportions and their standard errors (using either inverse variance weights or some random effects version)

   - This is trivially easy to implement.
   - Will often be a poor approximation for small proportions/with small sample sizes (i.e. when normal approximation to likelihood is poor).
   - As you say, it ignores the underlying time-to-event process/cannot deal with censoring appropriately.
2. 1-step meta-analysis e.g. using random effects logistic regression

   - Trivially easy to implement.
   - Avoids approximation with normal likelihood.
   - Still ignores that it's really a time-to-event process.
3. 2-step meta-analysis of something like suitably transformed estimates of the survival probability from a time-to-event analysis on each study (or digitizing the Kaplan-Meier curve and then re-analyzing etc.).

   - Slightly more complex, unless analysis already done.
   - Makes normal approximation.
   - Reflects that this is time-to-event.
   - May not have to assume specific time-to-event distribution (can use non-/semi-parametric approach).
   - Admits both random and fixed effects approaches.
4. 1-step parametric time-to-event model such as Weibull with e.g. random study effects on  selected parameters.

   - More complex, but avoids normal approx.
   - Reflects that this is TTE.
   - Assumes specific time-to-event distributions and admits both random/fixed effects.

There's almost certainly quite a few more reasonable options. There's usually many options to do any one thing.

I'd assume that option (1) would be covered in standard meta-analysis packages, and (3) likely, too, if you do the right pre-processing and the right analyses have already been done. The other options may require you to use your own analyses and piece them together appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I assume that the distribution may vary across studies so I would be using a random effects approach. Option 3 seems a good trade-off between complexity and strength of assumptions. To clairfy, by 'right pre-processing and the right analysis' do you mean calculating the estimates of survival probability for each study (e.g. by digitizing and re-analyzing the K-M curves)? Would it be then a reasonable approach to logit-transform the probabilities, caluclate the variance of logit-transformed probabilities based on the number of patients at risk?

Comment: 2/ If so, would it be appropriate to use escalc() function from the 'metafor' package and rma() to fit the model, or do you know of a meta-analysis package that I can use?

Comment: Yes, meta-analyzing KM estimates with SEs on some suitable transformed scale is what I meant with option 3. I'm not sure how well logit transformation will work here. It may be totally fine, just never looked into it/never saw publicaitons on that. I've more often seen transformations for Kaplan-Meier estimates (+- SE) being log-log- or Hall-Wellner (arcsine-square root transform), and a few others, which one could otherwise use very similarly to logit transformed values. You would not want to calculate the SEs from the number at risk, you'd want the actual time-to-event-based estimate of it.

Comment: I don't know the `metafor` package that well, but if you take approach (3), then standard functions for fixed- and random-effects meta-analysis should be usable.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure what exactly you would like to do, but generally, you are able to compare more than one risk designs into one group for meta-analysis purposes. Regression coefficients, Incidence risk ratios, etc. See for example this meta analysis (https://ies.fsv.cuni.cz/sci/publication/show/id/6745/lang/en) page 3 and 4 for details.